# Load data "namespace not available"

Tags: r, import

I have received a bunch of data saved with the `save` function of R.

When I try to load it, I got a Warning about the namespace and so finally an error. Is there a way to sort that out and to recover the data ?

```
> load('mydata')
Warning: namespace ‘BMP’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘res’
Error: ReadItem: unknown type 0, perhaps written by later version of R
```

I know that `BMP` is a function used to generate the data, and that `res` is one of the elements contained in `mydata`.

Comment: On which versions of R did you write, and attempt to read, the data?

Comment: Have you tried loading the package from which `BMP` comes?

Comment: @Roland ok just tried it and the warning disappeared. However still got the error

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen data has been saved on R/3.2.1 and I'm on R/3.2.2

Comment: When you saved your workspace was there any error or did R crash?

Comment: Yet I don't have the log I have just been sent the results. I'll try to get it.

Comment: well he doesn't have the log anymore but just told me I got the warnings but no error. Maybe the files are corrupter with the ftp transfer. I'll try to sort that out once accessing by myself the original cluster